# Mediation analysis with as.factor() independent variable

Tags: r, mediator

I am trying to run a mediation analysis but I have a factor in my IV. This seems to be causing some issues. Here's an example:

```
data(iris)
library(mediation)
ols.0 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length + as.factor(Species), data = iris)

ols.med <- lm(Sepal.Width ~ Petal.Length + as.factor(Species), data = iris)

ols.y <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length + Sepal.Width + as.factor(Species), data = iris)

results1 <- mediate(ols.med, ols.y, treat="Petal.Length", mediator="Sepal.Width", boot=TRUE, sims=500)
```

So I can run the lm() commands just fine, but when I run the mediate() command, I get this error message:

```
Running nonparametric bootstrap

Error in is.factor(x) : object 'Species' not found
```

Is there a way to handle factor variables when running the mediate() command, or are there alternative packages/methods that I should consider?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to create the `as.factor` outside as this could change the `call` attribute name. If we want to use the `as.factor` inside the `formula`, wrap it in `I` or make the changes in the attribute

```
iris$Species <- as.factor(iris$Species)
ols.0 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length + Species, data = iris)

ols.med <- lm(Sepal.Width ~ Petal.Length + Species, data = iris)

 ols.y <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length + Sepal.Width + Species, data = iris)

results1 <- mediate(ols.med, ols.y, treat="Petal.Length", 
       mediator="Sepal.Width", boot=TRUE, sims=500)



str(results1)
List of 56
 $ d0           : num 0.129
 $ d1           : num 0.129
 $ d0.ci        : Named num [1:2] 0.0642 0.21
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "2.5%" "97.5%"
 $ d1.ci        : Named num [1:2] 0.0642 0.21
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "2.5%" "97.5%"
 $ d0.p         : num 0
 $ d1.p         : num 0
 $ d0.sims      : num [1:500, 1] 0.111 0.137 0.197 0.116 0.215 ...
 $ d1.sims      : num [1:500, 1] 0.111 0.137 0.197 0.116 0.215 ...
 $ z0           : num 0.776
 $ z1           : num 0.776
 $ z0.ci        : Named num [1:2] 0.636 0.907
# ..
```